# Javascript in HTMLPanel

Tags: javascript, html, gwt, panel

I want to include Javascript code in a HTMLPanel element, but it is not working. Could you please help me? Thanks in advance.

**Scripts/pro.js**

```
alert('hello');
```

***WITH HTMLPANEL DOES NOT WORK (no alert is displayed)***

**MyPage.java (which is EntryPoint for MyPage.html)**

```
String preHtml="<script type=\"text/javascript\" src=\"Scripts/pro.js\"></script>";
HTMLPanel prePanel=new HTMLPanel(preHtml);
RootPanel.get("scriptContainer").add(prePanel);
```

**MyPage.html**

```
<td align="left" valign="top" id="scriptContainer"></td>
```

***WITHOUT HTMLPANEL DOES WORK (alert is displayed)***

**MyPage.html**

```
<td align="left" valign="top"><script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/pro.js"></script></td>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it should be other way around. The HTMLPanel quoting the javadocs

> A panel that contains HTML, and which can attach child widgets to identified
>     elements within that HTML.

should wrap your container not your script. The below example works unless you absolutely have a reason to use HTMLPanel to wrap a script.

```
HTMLPanel html = new HTMLPanel("<table><tr><td id='scriptContainer'></td></tr></table>");
RootPanel.get().add(html);  
Element script = DOM.createElement("script");
DOM.setElementAttribute(script,"language","JavaScript");
DOM.setElementAttribute(script,"src","Scripts/pro.js");
DOM.appendChild(DOM.getElementById("scriptContainer"),script);
```

Comment: I tried it again but it is not working. Please find more information in edited question. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Brilliant! Now it works. If I want to add this HTMLPanel to one specific point of MyPage.html, should I write <div id="here"></div> and then on MyPage.java do RootPanel.get("here").add(html)? It seems it does not work...

Comment: In fact the code above does not work if we change the alert('hello') for a document.write("Hello"). I guess it is related to the RootPanel.get().add(html)...

Comment: Problem is document.write(), it writes the document as a whole. If you want to insert text generated by a javascript into certain places in your document, I would suggest using innerHTML. Each HTML element has an innerHTML property that defines both the HTML code and the text that occurs between that element's opening and closing tag. Here is an example js : document.getElementById("scriptContainer").innerHTML = "Hello"; and yes you can create a div with an id in your html page and add your html panel or any widget by using RootPanel.get("id").add(widget);

Comment: I was also facing the same problem regarding the use of js in html panel, so followed the solution given above but i m getting a onModuleLoad() Exection
-------------------------------------------------------
Caused by: com.google.gwt.core.client.JavaScriptException: (TypeError): Object [object global] has no method 'appendChild