# GWT <script> tag not loading properly

Tags: java, javascript, html, facebook, gwt

I have defined in my head tag a function `<script> functionX(a,b,c) ....</script>`

which calls some third party js. The actual function is this:

```
    <script>
    function fbc(d, s, id) 
    {     var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
          if    (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}    
          js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;      
          js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1";  
          fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);   
    }
    </script>
```

and later on I want to call that function. I'm calling it using and HTML widget in the following way:

```
    HTML html = new HTML();
    setHTML(
            "<script>"+
            "   fbcomment(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk');   "+
            "</script> "+  
            "<fb:comments width=\"600\" num_posts=\"2\" href=\"http://www.woojah.com\"></fb:comments>");
```

However, it is not executing properly. Any advice would be very useful.

Comment: this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7057312/javascript-in-htmlpanel/7062184#7062184) could be of help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is more idiomatic to call external functions using [JSNI](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideCodingBasicsJSNI.html):

```
native void facebookComment(Document d, String s, String id) /*-{
  fbc(d, s, id);
}-*/;

void myFunction() {
  facebookComment(Document.get(), "script", "facebook-jssdk");
}
```

Comment: Thank you. That actually worked, but it only works the first time. When the comment plugin appear for the first time it is perfect, but then if I draw something else (If I change page dynamicaly for example), and I go back to the comment, It wont redraw. It only works the first time.

Comment: The reason is that the Facebook script parses and renders XFBML markup only when it is first loaded. So if you change page dynamicaly, you get some new XFBML markup and you have to parse the page again, using the function FB.XFBML.parse(). See http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.XFBML.parse/